# Is there a way to *not* have to capture variables by reference in this?

Tags: c++, gpu

I'm trying to do matrix multiplication in parallel using the NVIDIA HPC SDK's stdpar implementation, and ran into a problem.

Is there any way I can accomplish the following *without* having to capture the variables by reference inside the lambdas? My goal is to run the loops on the GPU as well.

I'm trying to compile this using the `nvc++` compiler using the `-stdpar` flag, which does not allow capture by reference, as it would likely cause an illegal memory access when run on the GPU.

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<T>> result;
std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, A.begin(), A.end(),
                  [&](auto a) {
                      std::vector<T> tmp(A.size());
                      tmp.reserve(A.size());
                      std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, tB.begin(), tB.end(),
                                    [&](auto b) {
                                        tmp.push_back(std::transform_reduce(
                                            std::execution::par_unseq, 
                                            a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), 0.0)
                                        );
                                    });
                      result.push_back(tmp);
                  });
```

Comment: Look like a [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) instead of a `for_each`.

Comment: I don't know anything about programming GPUs, but calling `std::vector::push_back()` in a loop is always a bad idea (unless this compiler does something rather unusual in the implementation). Also, is default `std::allocator` really using GPU memory in this compiler? It doesn't really look like you are using anything GPU related based on this code alone.

Comment: GPUs aside, this has a data race trying to access `result` in parallel!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar question. I don't have enough reputation to comment, but per the NVIDIA docs:

> For example, std::vector uses dynamically allocated memory, which is accessible from the GPU when using stdpar. Iterating over the contents of std::vector in a C++ Parallel Algorithm works as expected:

It does say in the docs that you can't do capture by reference, but they were talking about an `std::array` in that context which is not dynamically allocated internally.

So I guess my point is, if you were using `std::vector` which is dynamically allocated internally, (and you are) it might work according to the docs. Did you try it?

As another side note, even if it did not have a memory access issue, I don't think it would be a good idea to `push_back` within a parallel loop because it would be a race condition, which means that the result of that vector you're pushing into would depend on which thread ran at what time. It may have correct answers but they might be out of order.

I'm not sure how to avoid the race condition, I'm trying to figure that exact thing out myself as well with code similar to yours but I'm not using NVIDIA HPC.

I understand this may not fully answer your question but I'm not able to just comment due to reputation. I hope you figured out a solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32437526)